# How to put file names in mutable arrays?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I'm developing for iOS. how can I put in a NSMutableArray all file names that are present in the app? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSString path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];
```

This should give you content inside the .app folder. If you have files inside subfolders, you'll have to check if the file returned is a file or folder, and get the files inside recursively